# Azure Active Directory Login Error

Tags: azure, active-directory

When I loging to Azure AD I got page like this..
But I need JSON token in return when login is success ..

[Click here to view error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0geP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Which account did you login to create the AD ? You need to relogin as that account and go to Setting>Administrators, add the AD to Co-administrator. Then you will login using that AD account. Go to the page below:
[image]